# CollectionView AutoResize Label Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, collectionview

I have a vertical collectionview with label and in my flowlayout i am using **`UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`** to resize the cell size  but it is giving me error when i give very long string to the label, number of line in **`label`** set to 0

**Error**

> Please check the values returned by the delegate.
>    The relevant
>
> UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is UICollectionViewFlowLayout ,and
>   it is attached to UICollectionView; frame = (0 88; 375 690);
>   clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = NSArray
>   layer = CALayer; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 2};
>   adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout:
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the
>   debugger.
>
> The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because
>   the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView
>   minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content
>   insets left and right values

**Constraints**

[image]

**Code**

```
let array = ["Hello", Array(repeating: "Hello", count: 100).joined(), "blah"]
// on viewDidLoad method
 if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        flowLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at the following link, not sure if it will help. [Github](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/issues/80). There is an answer provided  rnystrom on 20 Oct 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that for some reason `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` does not set maximum width of the the cell, and since you have constraints set like you do, what happens is that `width` of a cell or multiple cells is bigger than width of the `collectionView`.

Here is how to fix it, add a `width` constraint to your label inside of your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and set it not to `equal` but to `less than equal`.

[image: Add a constraint]

Next make an outlet to that constraint so that it will be possible to be set later.

[image: Outlet]

Then in `CollectionViewDataSource` `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you can set the width constant to be smaller than `CollectionView` width minus  padding you added (in my case label has padding 20 + 20 for left and right).

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuse", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.widthConstraint.constant = collectionView.bounds.size.width - 40
    //line above sets maximum width of label to be maximum the width of the collection view
    cell.label.text = array[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

The result is collection view like below:

[image]

Comment: Oh my constraints for label are 20 for top left right and bottom

Comment: when i scroll or reload items my layout become little bit weird, https://imgur.com/a/zSdrCGj

Comment: I would play with content compression and content hughing values: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef

Comment: If not you will have to size cells by yourself since then you have all control over how it works